# Insert into hive table is taking lot of time from spark sql - performance issue

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, query-optimization

It is taking lot of time to insert records into hive table.

Table definition:

```
 CREATE TABLE dq_status(                          
   application_id string,                         
   application_name string,                       
   start_time string,                             
   end_time string,                               
   job_description string,                        
   status string)                                 
 ROW FORMAT SERDE                                   
   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'  
 WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (                             
   'field.delim'=',',                               
   'serialization.format'=',')                      
 STORED AS INPUTFORMAT                              
   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'  
 OUTPUTFORMAT                                       
   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
```

Spark Sql version: 2.4.0-cdh6.2.1

It is an unpartitioned table. The problem with the table it has 1400 small files. But for inserting few records I don't know why it is taking 10 mins. Performance is varying. Sometimes it is inserting in 10 secs, sometimes it is taking close to 10 mins.

Attached screenshots:
Total Query time - 10 mins. But Job within Query took only 1 sec. I don't know what was happening for remaining mins. In this case, i am just inserting only one record in hive table. Since we don't have any other databases in our Big data cluster, we are using hive DB

[image]
[image]
[image]

Please help! Let me know if additional log information is required.[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Comment: Hi @arvinth , have you got the solution for this, if yes can you please kindly share.

Comment: @ Albin Chandy  Main issue there were lot of small files in the hive. Once table compaction was done. Insert operation was much faster.   Sorry for the late response